# Extends Fragment screen with inheritance?

Tags: android, architecture, mvp

I have implemented the UI for the screen attached in a class OrderFragmentDetails, is the same screen for buyer and seller flows. The only difference is the behavior of the button confirm order. I am considering 2 options:

1 - Extends OrderFragmentDetails for buyer and seller:
OrderBuyerFragmentDetails and OrderSellerFragmentDetails(i am using MVP so create also 2 presenters that extends from OrderFragmentDetailsPresenter)

2 - Pass an argument in the creation of the fragment and decide the logic in OrderFragmentDetailsPresenter. The cons for this is the code does not look very extensible...Whereas on the 1st case looks a bit overkill creating 2 classes for just a different call in the button, plus i am not a big fan of extending UI.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would've** have 1 fragment and 2 presenters. Similar to your second option, but with logic separation. Inject proper presenter based on the parameter you send when creating your fragment instance.

Basically since you have **the same UI** you should reuse **the same view (Fragment)**, and since you have **different logic** you **can have different presenters**.

At this point you should compare two options: **having one presenter vs having two presenters**.

If your **sell/buy logic** is **small** it might be ok to have just **one presenter with state**, that you'll just pass from your fragment.

If the **logic is medium-sized or big** better to have **2 presenters**.

Comment: Definitely 2 presenters. However i always thought the relation between fragment and presenter was 1 to 1...